# Can't change FBSDKLoginButton position

Tags: swift, facebook, sdk

I'm have the Facebook login button to my app, but when I can't move it from the top left corner to the center of the screen. 
I tried:

```
 loginButton.center = (self.view?.center)!
```

and

```
loginButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX,y :self.frame.midY), size: CGSize(width: loginButton.frame.width, height: loginButton.frame.height))
```

but neither worked, the center variable changes but the button remains in the top left corner

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

I'm adding the button with this code

```
let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
        let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
        button.readPermissions = ["email"]
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
    }()
view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Comment: How are you adding the button to view? Please share the line of code you are using to add the button.

Comment: let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
            let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
            button.readPermissions = ["email"]
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
        }()  
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your code like this:

```
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: //whatever width you want, height: //whatever height you want))
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]
    loginButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#loginkit